# nuxt bundleRenderer directive does not work

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I created a directive with name 'can' to check user permissions and then renders some content only for users who have required access but it doesn't work.

Here is what I have tried

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
module.export = {
// other configs
ssr: true,
  render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      directives: {
        can (elm, binding, vnode) {
          // check if the user has the permission render the element
          // const has_permission = check user have my-permission;
          if (!has_permission) {
            elm.remove();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

**my-component.vue**

```html
<nuxt-link v-can="'my-permission'"></nuxt-link>
```

Comment: I quote the documentation: `It is recommended to not use this option as Nuxt is already providing best SSR defaults and misconfiguration might lead to SSR problems.`. Also, why do you need this and especially here? Cannot you simply use a `v-if` in your templates?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any suggestion for adding these kinds of directive ?

Comment: Wrap your tempalte parts into a conditional `v-if`, pretty much as you did here.